# Decode protocol buffer data received over websocket

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, protocol-buffers

I need to decode some data that I receive from a websocket. The json-data from the websocket looks something like the following

```
{'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameReceived","params":{"requestId":"492426.93","response":{"mask":false,"opcode":2,"payloadData":"LAAAAAEAAgcAAAgAAAkAAAsD/////w0DAgAAABEA8pRHBhMmAgBil11VOqhCPwAA"},"timestamp":1520143.671975}},"webview":"404CD2F0F548ADD45041D57D15ABF8D3"}',
  'timestamp': 1674936083381},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameSent","params":{"requestId":"492426.89","response":{"mask":true,"opcode":2,"payloadData":"DQAAAAgAAAEAAQcAjwI/AAA="},"timestamp":1520144.664665}},"webview":"404CD2F0F548ADD45041D57D15ABF8D3"}',
  'timestamp': 1674936084374},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameReceived","params":{"requestId":"492426.89","response":{"mask":false,"opcode":2,"payloadData":"LAAAAAEAAQcAjwIIAAAJAAALA/////8NAwIAAAARAOXIui4mAgBQn11VOqhCPwAA"},"timestamp":1520144.684971}},"webview":"404CD2F0F548ADD45041D57D15ABF8D3"}',
  'timestamp': 1674936084395},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameSent","params":{"requestId":"492426.105","response":{"mask":true,"opcode":2,"payloadData":"DAAAAAgAAAEAFQcAAD8AAA=="},"timestamp":1520144.936517}},"webview":"404CD2F0F548ADD45041D57D15ABF8D3"}',
  'timestamp': 1674936084646},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameReceived","params":{"requestId":"492426.105","response":{"mask":false,"opcode":2,"payloadData":"LAAAAAEAFQcAAAgAAAkAAAsD/////w0DAgAAABEA8YdRBhMmAgCcoV1VOqhCPwAA"},"timestamp":1520144.987374}},"webview":"404CD2F0F548ADD45041D57D15ABF8D3"}',
  'timestamp': 1674936084697}
```

In order to use this data I need to decode the payloadData-part. As far as I can tell I need to decode the data using a protocol buffer using a similar approach as described here [decode websocket received data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321908/decode-websocket-received-data/59382147#59382147). I guess I need to find the structture of the received messages inside the javascript on the home page where I receive the data from. I have located the following function, but not sure if this is actually the function that decode the data,

```
t.prototype.onMessage = function (t) {
      var i,
      o,
      s,
      l,
      d = this;
      e['binary-all'] && void 0 !== e['binary-all'][(null === (i = this.ps) || void 0 === i ? void 0 : i.pid) + '/' + (null === (o = this.ps) || void 0 === o ? void 0 : o.sid)] && e.binaryDump((null === (s = this.ps) || void 0 === s ? void 0 : s.pid) + '/' + (null === (l = this.ps) || void 0 === l ? void 0 : l.sid), new Uint8Array(t.data), !1),
      this.pingTimeout = 0,
      this.rawDebugCounter++;
      var u = null,
      c = 0;
      this.overflowBuffer ? (c = t.data.byteLength + this.overflowBuffer.length, (u = new Uint8Array(c)).set(this.overflowBuffer, 0), u.set(t.data, this.overflowBuffer.length), this.overflowBuffer = null) : (u = new Uint8Array(t.data), c = u.byteLength);
      for (var g = new e.Tag, m = 0, p = function () {
        var t = e.LowLevel.getInt32(u, m);
        if (t + m + 4 > c) return h.overflowBuffer = new Uint8Array(u, m, c - m),
        {
          value: void 0
        };
        m += 4;
        var i = new e.Parser(m, m + t);
        m += t;
        var o = new a(h.ps);
        if (o.segment = r.First, h.rawDebug) {
          for (h.rawDebugPackets++; i.next(u, g, h.tagSet); ) 123123123 == g.tag && (h.callbacks.forEach(function (t) {
            t.lowLevelError(o, e.HeaderResponses.Ok, 'Got tag 123123123')
          }), e.log('test')),
          h.rawDebugCounter++,
          h.rawDebugCounter % 1000000 << 0 == 0 && h.callbacks.forEach(function (t) {
            t.lowLevelError(o, e.HeaderResponses.Ok, 'pkts: ' + d.rawDebugPackets.toString() + ' tags: ' + d.rawDebugCounter.toString())
          });
          return 'continue'
        }
        for (var s = e.HeaderResponses.Ok, l = ''; i.next(u, g, h.tagSet); ) {
          if (g.tag === e.HeaderTags.End) {
            i.setHeaderEnd();
            break
          }
          switch (g.tag) {
            case e.HeaderTags.PID:
              h.websocket.localLoop && (o.pid = g.int(u));
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.SID:
              h.websocket.localLoop && (o.sid = g.int(u));
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.SeqNu:
              h.seqNu = g.int(u);
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.Request:
              o.request = g.int(u),
              o.clientServer = !0;
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.UserData:
              o.userData = g.int(u);
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.UniqueId:
              o.uniqueId = g.int(u);
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.ReplyNu:
              o.segment = g.int(u);
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.ResponseId:
              s = g.int(u);
              break;
            case e.HeaderTags.Response:
              l = g.string(u)
          }
        }
        var p = !1;
        if (h.logServerDetails && o.responseMsg && e.log(o.psToStr(), 'Response', o.idStr(), o.responseMsg), void 0 !== o.request) switch (o.request) {
          case e.HeaderRequests.Subscribe:
          case e.HeaderRequests.Unsubscribe:
          case e.HeaderRequests.ChangeSubscriptions:
            p = !0;
            break;
          case e.HeaderRequests.Ping:
            h.monitorServerConnection || (p = !0);
            break;
          case e.HeaderRequests.LoginProvider:
            var f = (new Date).getTime() - h.startLoginProvider.getTime();
            h.callbacks.forEach(function (e) {
              e.lowLevelConnect && e.lowLevelConnect(d.ps, f)
            }),
            p = s == e.HeaderResponses.Ok,
            h.status.connectionAttemptCount = 0,
            h.status.connectionState !== n.Closing && h.setConnectionState(n.Running);
            break;
          case e.HeaderRequests.StartRealtime:
            p = s == e.HeaderResponses.Ok,
            h.firstConnection && s == e.HeaderResponses.Restart && (p = !0, s = e.HeaderResponses.Ok),
            h.firstConnection = !1,
            h.status.lastSuccessfulConnectTime = Date.now();
            break;
          case e.HeaderRequests.LoginAuthentication:
        }
        if (p) return 'continue';
        switch (s) {
          case e.HeaderResponses.Ok:
            break;
          case e.HeaderResponses.Restart:
            return h.logServerDetails && e.log(h.ps.toStr(), 'HeaderResponse restart'),
            h.seqNu = 0,
            h.startRealtime(),
            h.callbacks.forEach(function (e) {
              e.lowLevelReRequestAll && e.lowLevelReRequestAll(o)
            }),
            'continue';
          case e.HeaderResponses.Error:
            return h.logServerDetails && e.log(h.ps.toStr(), 'HeaderResponse error:', l),
            h.callbacks.forEach(function (e) {
              e.lowLevelError && e.lowLevelError(o, s, l)
            }),
            'continue';
          default:
            h.logServerDetails && e.log(h.ps.toStr(), 'HeaderResponse', e.HeaderResponsesToStr(s) + ':', l),
            h.callbacks.forEach(function (e) {
              e.lowLevelError && e.lowLevelError(o, s, l)
            })
        }
        h.data(o, u, i)
      }, h = this; m < c; ) {
        var f = p();
        if ('object' == typeof f) return f.value
      }
      g = null
    }
```

Can anyone tell if this is actually the function that decode the data packages, and if so, how can the decoding be done in python?

Comment: Posting minified code is *really* not helpful.

Comment: Hi tadman, sorry I am new here, what is minified code?

Comment: That JavaScript may as well be assembly code, it has meaningless variable names and function names, and is compacted to near unreadability.