# Reconstruct proto schema from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I need to decode binary messages that I receive over a Websocket. The messages seem to be encoded using a protocol buffer, but I do not have access to the .proto file. By reading this example [decode websocket received data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321908/decode-websocket-received-data/59382147#59382147) I am guessing I should be able to reconstruct the .proto file from the JavaScript on the page where I receive the messages. However, I have no clue what to look for in the JavaScript files. Does anyone have ideas on what to search for in the JavaScript, or an alternative method to extract the protocol buffer schema?

The onmessage function from the JavaScript has the following content

```
t.prototype.onMessage = function(t) {
        var i, o, s, l, d = this;
        e["binary-all"] && void 0 !== e["binary-all"][(null === (i = this.ps) || void 0 === i ? void 0 : i.pid) + "/" + (null === (o = this.ps) || void 0 === o ? void 0 : o.sid)] && e.binaryDump((null === (s = this.ps) || void 0 === s ? void 0 : s.pid) + "/" + (null === (l = this.ps) || void 0 === l ? void 0 : l.sid), new Uint8Array(t.data), !1),
        this.pingTimeout = 0,
        this.rawDebugCounter++;
        var u = null
          , c = 0;
        this.overflowBuffer ? (c = t.data.byteLength + this.overflowBuffer.length,
        (u = new Uint8Array(c)).set(this.overflowBuffer, 0),
        u.set(t.data, this.overflowBuffer.length),
        this.overflowBuffer = null) : (u = new Uint8Array(t.data),
        c = u.byteLength);
        for (var g = new e.Tag, m = 0, p = function() {
            var t = e.LowLevel.getInt32(u, m);
            if (t + m + 4 > c)
                return h.overflowBuffer = new Uint8Array(u,m,c - m),
                {
                    value: void 0
                };
            m += 4;
            var i = new e.Parser(m,m + t);
            m += t;
            var o = new a(h.ps);
            if (o.segment = r.First,
            h.rawDebug) {
                for (h.rawDebugPackets++; i.next(u, g, h.tagSet); )
                    123123123 == g.tag && (h.callbacks.forEach(function(t) {
                        t.lowLevelError(o, e.HeaderResponses.Ok, "Got tag 123123123")
                    }),
                    e.log("test")),
                    h.rawDebugCounter++,
                    h.rawDebugCounter % 1e6 << 0 == 0 && h.callbacks.forEach(function(t) {
                        t.lowLevelError(o, e.HeaderResponses.Ok, "pkts: " + d.rawDebugPackets.toString() + " tags: " + d.rawDebugCounter.toString())
                    });
                return "continue"
            }
            for (var s = e.HeaderResponses.Ok, l = ""; i.next(u, g, h.tagSet); ) {
                if (g.tag === e.HeaderTags.End) {
                    i.setHeaderEnd();
                    break
                }
                switch (g.tag) {
                case e.HeaderTags.PID:
                    h.websocket.localLoop && (o.pid = g.int(u));
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.SID:
                    h.websocket.localLoop && (o.sid = g.int(u));
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.SeqNu:
                    h.seqNu = g.int(u);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.Request:
                    o.request = g.int(u),
                    o.clientServer = !0;
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.UserData:
                    o.userData = g.int(u);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.UniqueId:
                    o.uniqueId = g.int(u);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.ReplyNu:
                    o.segment = g.int(u);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.ResponseId:
                    s = g.int(u);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderTags.Response:
                    l = g.string(u)
                }
            }
            var p = !1;
            if (h.logServerDetails && o.responseMsg && e.log(o.psToStr(), "Response", o.idStr(), o.responseMsg),
            void 0 !== o.request)
                switch (o.request) {
                case e.HeaderRequests.Subscribe:
                case e.HeaderRequests.Unsubscribe:
                case e.HeaderRequests.ChangeSubscriptions:
                    p = !0;
                    break;
                case e.HeaderRequests.Ping:
                    h.monitorServerConnection || (p = !0);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderRequests.LoginProvider:
                    var f = (new Date).getTime() - h.startLoginProvider.getTime();
                    h.callbacks.forEach(function(e) {
                        e.lowLevelConnect && e.lowLevelConnect(d.ps, f)
                    }),
                    p = s == e.HeaderResponses.Ok,
                    h.status.connectionAttemptCount = 0,
                    h.status.connectionState !== n.Closing && h.setConnectionState(n.Running);
                    break;
                case e.HeaderRequests.StartRealtime:
                    p = s == e.HeaderResponses.Ok,
                    h.firstConnection && s == e.HeaderResponses.Restart && (p = !0,
                    s = e.HeaderResponses.Ok),
                    h.firstConnection = !1,
                    h.status.lastSuccessfulConnectTime = Date.now();
                    break;
                case e.HeaderRequests.LoginAuthentication:
                }
            if (p)
                return "continue";
            switch (s) {
            case e.HeaderResponses.Ok:
                break;
            case e.HeaderResponses.Restart:
                return h.logServerDetails && e.log(h.ps.toStr(), "HeaderResponse restart"),
                h.seqNu = 0,
                h.startRealtime(),
                h.callbacks.forEach(function(e) {
                    e.lowLevelReRequestAll && e.lowLevelReRequestAll(o)
                }),
                "continue";
            case e.HeaderResponses.Error:
                return h.logServerDetails && e.log(h.ps.toStr(), "HeaderResponse error:", l),
                h.callbacks.forEach(function(e) {
                    e.lowLevelError && e.lowLevelError(o, s, l)
                }),
                "continue";
            default:
                h.logServerDetails && e.log(h.ps.toStr(), "HeaderResponse", e.HeaderResponsesToStr(s) + ":", l),
                h.callbacks.forEach(function(e) {
                    e.lowLevelError && e.lowLevelError(o, s, l)
                })
            }
            h.data(o, u, i)
        }, h = this; m < c; ) {
            var f = p();
            if ("object" == typeof f)
                return f.value
        }
        g = null
    }
```

Comment: Just step through the code in the websocket `onmessage` handler. At some point you'll come across a piece of code that does the decoding.

Comment: "*an alternative method to extract the protocol buffer schema?*" - have you tried asking the application developers for an API documentation?

Comment: Hi Bergi, I have added the onmessage function to the post above, are you able to see if the schema can be reproduced from this?

Comment: Those `switch` statements look promising. I don't know the application, do any of a) the enums and b) the assigned properties make sense in the application domain? I would expect `e.HeaderTags` to contain the protobuf field ids. Try to inspect the value with the debugger. Also inspect the values of `o` (the output object?), `h` (possibly some kind of wrapper for protobuf-over-websocket?), `g` (the currently decoded field?) and `i` (the parser itself) if they have some useful properties that you can make sense of (at various stages of the decoding process).